# Symfony2 ajax and browser back-button

Tags: ajax, symfony, http-headers

I'm following this article ([Symfony2: Ajax and Full Page Templates](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2013/02/18/symfony2-ajax-and-full-page-templates/)) regarding using Ajax in my symfony2 web application.

As you can see in the article, I extend one template depending on the request (Ajax or not)

```
{% extends app.request.xmlHttpRequest ? 'DevmanagerCoreBundle::core-ajaxpage.html.twig' : 'DevmanagerCoreBundle::core-fullpage.html.twig' %}
```

In order to perform the navigation through browser button I'm currently using the History HTML5 API.

The problem is: When I click the back button (after an ajax call) why symfony2 detects the request like xmlhttprequest?